# Tree structured modelled in mongodb with materialized paths: how to write query in java to get all child nodes using parent path

Tags: java, mongodb

I have been reading a [tutorial on Modelling Tree Structures with Materialized Paths](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-materialized-paths/):

This tutorial includes a query for finding children by using the parent's path. But my problem is how to do the query in java.

I tried to implement this using the code below:

```java
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query .put("Path",  java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("/,Programing,/"));
DBCursor doc = example.find(query ); 

while(doc.hasNext())
{                        
    System.out.println(doc.next());
}
```

Comment: Well, have you printed the resulting query to run it against the MongoDB alone? If yes, what are the results? Of no, do it!

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you......i got in command prompt.....but using above java code i'm not getting.......

Comment: See, you have a problem with MongoDB and Java and you want to rule out where the problem is seated - so to rule out that your MongoDB query is wrong, you print the resulting query the Java program creates and pass it to Mongo: If the query works, your Java program has another problem, if the query does not work, the query is the first place to check.

Comment: i had tried in mongo it is working...but in java i'm not getting...can you plz give some suggestion  how to query in java.

Comment: i got it...  Pattern path1 = Pattern.compile("Programming");
         BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
         query.put("Path", path1);
         DBCursor doc = example.find(query);
       
      
         while(doc.hasNext())
         {         
         System.out.println(doc.next());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
          Pattern path = Pattern.compile("Programing");
          BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
          query.put("Path", path);

          DBCursor doc = example.find(query ); 

          while(doc.hasNext())
          {                    
            System.out.println(doc.next());
          }
```